# How can I apply for an Argentina Tourist Visa from India and which document required?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, argentina

I want to know the process of how to apply for Argentina tourist visa in India and that time which document required?

Comment: What does the website of the Argentine embassy in India say? What does the Argentine government website say? You should use official sources where possible, rather than relying on other people to get it right. If there's something specific you need to know, please do ask about that, but the information you're asking for at the moment should already be publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

https://eindi.cancilleria.gob.ar/
and here

https://eindi.cancilleria.gob.ar/en/content/information-concerning-visas-fees-application-form-general-considerations-and-specific-requi

the good news is, it is free :)

> Tourist visa for Indian nationals: free.

---

> INFORMATION CONCERNING VISAS (fees, application form, general
>   considerations and specific requirements)
>
> PLEASE READ ALL THE FOLLOWING INFORMATION THOROUGHLY and be sure that
>   you fulfill ALL the requirements established by law, to avoid any
>   delay in the process.
>
> Fees for Transitory visas
>
> -Tourist visa for Indian nationals: free.            Others: 150 US dollars
>   -Business visa (short term): 200 US dollars
>   -Visa for technicians: 200 US dollars
>   -Visa for Seafarers: Free
>
> Fees for Temporary or Permanent visas
>
> -Temporary or Permanent Work Visa: 250 US dollars
>
> Passengers in TRANSIT to other destinations, who stay in the premises
>   of the Argentine International Airport for less than 12hs, are not
>   required to have a visa stamped on their passport.
>
> E- VISA - ELECTRONIC TRAVEL AUTHORIZATION - ETA
>
> -Only for Passport holder of India, Nepal and Maldives, For TOURISM Purpose Only
>
> For the holders of Valid B2 US Visa (Valid for 6 months) OR For the
>   holders of valid Category C Schengen Visa (Valid for 6 months)
>   Validity of ETA will be 3 Months from date of issue Stay Period will
>   be 3 Months with multiple Entry/Exit Fees for ETA will be USD $ 50
>   Processing Time of ETA is 20 working Days For more information and to
>   start the process: http://www.migraciones.gov.ar/ave/index.htm
>
> For any query please write us to email: ave@migraciones.gov.ar
>
> GENERAL CONSIDERATIONS FOR ALL TYPES OF VISAS
>
> - You must apply for a visa at the Consular Section of the Embassy of the Argentine Republic in New Delhi, India, if your place of residence
>     is in Bangladesh, Bhutan, India, Maldives, Nepal or Sri Lanka, -
>     except Maharashtra and karnataka. Embassy's address: F-3/3 Vasant
>     Vihar, New Delhi 110057, India. Tel: (00 91) 11 - 4078 1900. Fax:
>     (0091) 11 - 40781901. Web: www.eindi.mrecic.gov.ar The Visas
>     Department is open to the public Monday to Friday, from 10:00 to 11:30
>     (for submission/collection of visa applications). The Consulate is
>     closed on Argentine and Indian holidays. All visa requests from
>     residents of Maharashtra and Karnataka, India, must apply at the
>     Consulate General of the Argentine Republic in Mumbai (CHANDER MUKHI
>     Building, 10TH Floor,   NARIMAN POINT – MUMBAI, 400 021   Mumbai,
>     India. Ph: (0091) 22 2287 1381 to 1383 www.cgmum.mrecic.gov.ar)
>
> HOW TO START THE PROCESS
>
> - Visa application forms accompanied by ALL the required documentation must be presented IN PAPER at this Consulate. Visa applications with
>     incomplete documentation will not be accepted. Translations must be
>     adequate; internet/online translations are not accepted. Please DO NOT
>     SUBMIT DOCUMENTS BY EMAIL, unless you are requested to do so by the
>     Consular Section. Only COMPLETE applications presented IN PAPER at the
>     Consulate will be considered. We suggest applicants to present their
>     applications at least 3 weeks before the expected date of travel to
>     avoid any inconveniences/delays.
> - The intervention of agents is NOT compulsory to perform paperwork in this Consulate.
> - Submitting false information either on the visa application documents or during the visa interview can lead to a finding of a
>     permanent ineligibility. Never submit your application without
>     reviewing it first.
> - Once the complete application is presented at the Consulate, it will be analyzed by the Chief of the Consular Section. Within the next 72
>     working hours, the applicant will be informed if any additional
>     documents are required, if there are any corrections to be done or if
>     he/she is able to come for the personal interview. Applicants will be
>     called to come for the interview once their applications fulfill ALL
>     the necessary requirements. Every applicant will be called to come in
>     person for the personal interview with a Consular Officer. This
>     interview is mandatory by law and admits no exceptions.
> - The applicable visa fees will be paid only after having been informed of visa approval by the Consular Officer, who will also
>     indicate where the bank deposit should be made. No cash is handled at
>     this Consulate; deposits are made in Indian Rupees. After the personal
>     interview, the approval of the visa and the payment of the
>     corresponding fee at the Bank, the visa will be processed within the
>     next 5 working days. Applicants will be informed when their visa is
>     ready. Please DO NOT CALL us, we will call you. In accordance with the
>     relevant laws of the Argentine Republic and the international practice
>     in the matter, please note that the Consul is entitled to refuse the
>     visa request.

Comment: @Willeke I don't think it's useful for us to be a mirror of the official sources, which will inevitably go out of date and potentially mislead people. It makes sense for things like Schengen, the UK and the USA because we get so many questions about those that the answers are likely to be kept up to date. But we don't get many questions from Indians wanting to travel to Argentina so it could be years before this gets updated.

Comment: I agree - the OP doesn’t seem to have done any prior research either.